# Not working in IE9; fadein(1000) fadeout(1000) show(1000) hide(1000)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a look at this page.

```
    http://103.1.173.226/site/
```

On firefox and chrome it works as it should, in IE9(dont know about IE 8 or other versions) it directly shows or hides the image instead of fading it.

More over, i have coded a function to display a slideshow of the images, showing one after another images. Now if you move from left towards right on the list below, the images show directly (as they are in that order in the page)however moving from right to left lag the showing of the next and hiding of the current image. This is happening because fadeIn and fadeOut are not working. And i have tried working on every solution found here for making fadein and fadeout work on IE, but nothing works, like some people suggested changes in css etc, i have tried them all.
Please help fast as I am on a strict deadline :S

The second problem is not important, working of fadeIn and Out will work this out.

Comment: Maybe you should paste the code you need help with, instead of letting all of us going through your entire code...

Comment: this is going to be public soon, so it doesnt matter if I share the website. And I am just fading images' divs on mouse hovering event, nothing else in the code.

Comment: @erizias is talking about us having to actually go to your site and dig through all of your code to find the corresponding bit you mention in your question. Make it easier for others to help you!

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui thanks for coming back and giving your feedback since everything was so important

Comment: ^^ I stated that it was kind of an urgent issue so I didnt have time to make a fiddle or something similar. Of course I mentioned my research in the question and the solution didnt come out of "research". So please get enough evidence before downvoting a question. 

By the way I was unbinding the mousemove event in the function of binding the same event, in a condition which hardly gets true and IE couldnt handle it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED::::I was unbinding the mousemove event in the function of binding the same event, in a condition which hardly gets true and IE couldnt handle it well.

Answer (score 1):

It's something to do with your position

```
#home .overview .background{
    position:absolute;
}
```

in your `styles.css`

If I uncheck it in developer mode it fades in and out fine in IE9

Comment: position was a problem too though, but it was solved without changing it. I was unbinding the mousemove event in a condition which hardly gets true